# Image won't show up on NPM, but shows up on Github

Tags: node.js, github, npm, markdown

Working on this repo for an NPM module

the image shows up on Github (scroll down)

https://github.com/ORESoftware/suman

[image]

but on NPM, despite an HTTP 200 to retrieve the image from Github, it doesn't show up

https://www.npmjs.com/package/suman

this is all Markdown, and the markdown for the image is:

```
![alt text](https://github.com/ORESoftware/suman/blob/master/images/suman.png "Suman Primary Logo")
```

Anyone know why this markdown image tag doesn't work on NPM?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this url (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORESoftware/suman/master/images/suman.png)

Your url link to a page not a image

Answer (score 1):

This is because the url

```
https://github.com/mvsowndapan/react-dnd-crop/blob/master/asset/icons/labelIcon.png
```

requesting to the github page that contains the image, not the image itself.

To get the image just add `?raw=true` at the end of the url

```
https://github.com/mvsowndapan/react-dnd-crop/blob/master/asset/icons/labelIcon.png?raw=true
```

like this. It works fine

Comment: Nope, still gives a 404.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because (for reasons that escape me) NPM interprets *relative* URLs incorrectly.

This will not work:

```
![ImageAlt](./path/image_name.jpg)
```

This works fine:

```
![ImageAlt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your_name/your_repo/your_branch/path/image_name.jpg)
```

The easiest way to get the right URL is to navigate to the image, right click it, and click "Open Image in New Tab." The URL should include `raw.githubusercontent.com` for NPM to correctly resolve it.